# No module named 'chartit';

Tags: django

I am trying to use chartit in django and in its documentation it says add chartit to INSTALLED APPS in "settings.py".
 When I try to do that, it gives this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'chartit'
```

How do I import it?
Thank you.
PS-Sorry, it's a silly question.

Comment: Do you use `virtualenv`? If yes, remove your virtualenv and recreate it, and show us all your console output (from `makevirtualenv`, `pip install`, etc.)

Comment: No, I am not using virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You missed installing it with `pip install django_chartit`.

**EDIT**:
The error you described is thrown by python if a module is not found in the running environment. You need to make sure, that you've installed it in the environment that is used by your django.

Try typing `pip list` in the shell you usually use to kick your django with `python manage.py runserver` to figure out what is installed there.

If your django lives inside of a IDE like PyCharm - you need to check the project settings there for the environment used to launch django.

As you don't use virtualenv (which is highly recommended) you install your modules system wide. If you are on linux there might be python3 and python (which is python 2). If your pip belongs to python2 and you have installed django in python3 or vice versa this might be the issue.

Comment: I had installed it like you said.

Comment: what does `pip list` say?

Comment: The package is listed there.:`django-chartit (0.2.7)`

Comment: How can I do that? What type of information is needed? I am new to django.

Comment: it has nothing to do with django in general, but with your python environment. As written in the updated answer it is all about where your pip, python and django are installed. Those differs depending on your operating system and, if you use one, your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

from chartit import DataPool, Chart